# Dynamic Programming Breaking a String

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The goal is to calculate the cost of breaking the string at the break points given by the user. So lets assume the following:
The length of String =  10 so lengthArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
and BreakPointArray = [5, 3, 2, 6, 1]. Now we do not have to change the order of the breaks given by the user.

I am able to figure out the tree structure for this problem

[image]

So the total cost of breaking the String at the breakPoints given = 10+5+5+3+2 = 25
However I am not able to come up with the implementation part. Below is my approach :

I start from BreakPoint = 5 and divide the lengthArray into

leftLength = [1,2,3,4,5]

and

rightLength = [6,7,8,9,10]

at BreakPoint = 3 , I check that it should come under leftLength Array so again I divide leftLength into 2 parts

leftLength1 = [1, 2,3]

and

rightLength1 = [4,5]

at BreakPoint = 2, come under leftLength1 so again divide into 2 parts

leftLength2 = [1,2] and

rightLength2 = [3]

Now I get stuck when BreakPoint = 6, since it comes under rightLength above. Can someone please help how can i keep track of all the partitions I have done . How can i go back to first rightLength array to compute cost for breakPoint 6. I am trying to implement this Java.

Comment: I am just writing the pseudo code before i implement in Java and I am getting no further at the point when BreakPoints are random. If you want I can share that

Comment: Can't you just build a tree of the resulting arrays and the cost at each non-leaf node? It should then not be difficult to find the node containing the array which currently contains element 6.

Comment: I don't even understand what your cost function and your optimization goal is - could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I have not reached the optimization part yet , this is the first step  to compute the total cost of all breakpoints in the array that too in the same order as they are given. After I achieve this I will run the computation for all combinations of BreakPoints given by the user and find out the cheapest combination along with the cost

Comment: If you just want to compute the cost of the entire process just use recursion and return the cost at each step. If you want to return the configuration that produces an optimal solution, you can include that in the return value.

Comment: What is the cost of a break point, i.e. how is it defined? And what does break point 6 mean? Splitting the string after 6 characters? And what is the overall goal? Splitting the string into n pieces with minimum costs? If so, where does the n come from? Or is it splitting the string into a maximum number of pieces given a upper limit on the costs? I have never heard of that problem and your question leaves me completely clueless how the problem is defined. What is lengthArray? How is the ordering of the break points relevant?

Comment: @DanielBrückner - You are breaking a ruler in the points listed consequentially. The cost of every operation is the length of ruler's part being breaking.  Task is to calculate total cost.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this is Lua, but DP algorithm is clear enough

```lua
-- input constants
local L = 0
local R = 10
local BreakPoints = {5, 3, 2, 6, 1}

-- fill the arrays
local NearestRight = {}
local NearestLeft = {}
for k = L, R do
   NearestRight[k] = R
   NearestLeft[k] = L
end

-- calculating cost
local cost = 0
for _, BreakPoint in ipairs(BreakPoints) do
   local left = NearestLeft[BreakPoint]
   local right = NearestRight[BreakPoint]
   cost = cost + (right - left)
   for k = left + 1, BreakPoint - 1 do
      NearestRight[k] = BreakPoint
   end
   for k = BreakPoint + 1, right - 1 do
      NearestLeft[k] = BreakPoint
   end
end
print(cost)   -- outputs 25
```

Time complexity is `O(cost)`